# invoke Apple Watch maps app for turn by turn directions

Tags: watchkit

I'm working on a watch app that will amongst other things need to get a person from point A to point B.

one option is to delegate the maps navigation work back to the iPhone and handle messaging updates between the watch and phone etc.

however does anyone know if its possible to simply invoke/launch the Apple Maps app (on the watch) directly from my own watch app and pass the start/end coordinate details -- to automatically initiate turn by turn directions (from the Apple Maps watch app) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second option sounds legit. According to WKInterfaceMap class reference, tapping on the map will directly open the Apple Watch Maps application.

Quoting from the documentation:

> A WKInterfaceMap object displays a noninteractive map for the location you specify. Maps must be configured dynamically from your interface controller. Use the methods of the WKInterfaceMap class to specify the visible region of the map and to add any annotations or points of interest. Tapping the map launches the Maps app on the user’s Apple Watch and displays the corresponding location.

Reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceMap_class/index.html

Comment: thanks very much Ashraf. looks like a classic (in my) case of "read the documentation" ! ill dig into this some more now, cheers.